# Degraded performance with TensorFlow 2.2.0-rc3

Tags: tensorflow

I just installed python 3.8.2, used pip to install tensorflow-gpu. It installed v2.2.0-rc3.
Everything works, it loads, reports its version and finds and correctly identifies GPUs on the system.

I pip install and run ai-benchmark and find the Inference score unchanged but the training score is 46% lower than my previous tests with python 3.7.6/TF-2.0. I'm using cuda 10.1, cudnn 10.1-linux-x64-v7.6.5.32.

Has anyone seen similar behavior or have any advice?

Comment: Additional information: the problem occurs only in the Inception-ResNet-V2 component of the benchmark, which seems to not run at all. Attempting to reproduce on a P100 and things ran just fine. Will attempt to reproduce on a V100 node when one becomes available.

Comment: Verified, the training task will run just fine on a P100 node, will not run on a V100 node. No changes to the code between the two runs.

Comment: The training task ran on a V100 after rollback. Rollback was python 3.8.2 to 3.7.6, gcc 9.1.0 to 7.4.0, cuda from 10.1 to 10.0 and TensorFlow from 2.2.0-rc3 to 2.0.0. For completness, the rolled back version also ran on a P100 node.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: TF2.2-rc3 has a problem. Will repeat the test when release is official and will not pre-release now,